# SQL, Receiving ERRORS

Tags: sql, error-handling

I was asked the following question:

Show the order number and the total amount of the order for all orders with a total amount less than or equal to $25.

I am trying to do the following, but am receiving error messages:

```
SELECT orderNumber, SUM(orderPrice * orderQuantity) AS orderTotal
FROM OrderProduct
WHERE (orderTotal < 25) OR (orderTotal = 25) 
GROUP BY orderNumber
```

I am getting a wreck of an error message so obviously I'm doing something wrong. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? MySQL? MS SQL? Oracle? ...?

Answer (score 3):

From a first glance I think you have to use `HAVING SUM(orderPrice * orderQuantity) <= 25` instead of the WHERE conditions.

So, your query should be like this:

```
SELECT orderNumber, SUM(orderPrice * orderQuantity) AS orderTotal
FROM OrderProduct
GROUP BY orderNumber
HAVING SUM(orderPrice * orderQuantity) <= 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **[having](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx)** clause in group by to check any condition on **[aggregate function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)**

```
SELECT orderNumber, SUM(orderPrice * orderQuantity) AS orderTotal
FROM OrderProduct
GROUP BY orderNumber 
having orderTotal <= 25
```

Comment: This may not work. I think it has to be `having SUM(orderPrice * orderQuantity) < = 25`

Comment: @Kaf: it does - at least on MySQL. See my Fiddle above :)

Comment: @Trinimon: Agree on mysql, I should have mentioned like "may not work on sql-server". Obviously user hasn't specified his DBMS, nothing wrong with the answer.

Comment: @Kaf it does work in **`SQL server`** too. In fact you can use **`column alias`** in **`order by`** too.

Comment: @Luv, you `can with order by` but `cannot with having` (again I am referring to sql server). [Check this out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5eb86/5), second query (having) does not work on latest sql server 2012. Order by works because it is the last thing done.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
SELECT orderNumber, SUM(orderPrice * orderQuantity) AS orderTotal
  FROM OrderProduct
 GROUP BY orderNumber 
HAVING orderTotal <= 25;
```

Check out [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbaa6/1).

On an ORACLE database use [*Radu Gheorghiu*'s](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbaa6/2) version.